# Exclude specific html tag and content inside it with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, tags

In my web application I want to display a short part of the body's content and for that I use PHP's `mb_substr()` function and that is OK and works fine. The problem is when that part of short content has a image tag that making mess in my design. I was wondering if PHP has any functions that exclude `img` tag with all content so I can use it before `mb_substr()` function, or I need to use javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP function [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) will remove “HTML and PHP tags from a string”

As you want to shorten some (HTML) text to a short text without HTML, that is probably what you are looking for!?

You may have a problem with `<img>` right now, but other HTML tags may be an issue in the future, right?

Comment: Content start with p tag and that isn't problem for me. Problem is only img tag that is in most case cuts on half because of mb_substr() show maybe 150 characters. `<img src="path/to/th...` Some posts has images after few paragraphs of text and I want to exclude it.

Comment: `<iframe>`will also be a problem.

Comment: And opening `<p>` tag requires a closing `</p>` tag to be present, so it very much is a problem if you want to generate valid HTML. It’s just not (as) visible.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strip_tags` and pass the html tags you wish to keep...